# ESP8266 SPI Запись и чтение в энерго независимую память

Tags: wifi, arduino, esp8266

Пытаюсь разобраться с (адресами) чтением и записью в память ESP8266.
Вот есть код

```
   char copy[1000];
   spi_flash_erase_sector(0x7c); //Очистка зачем она нужна непонятно но без нее не работает
   spi_flash_write(0x7c000, (uint32 *)&copy, sizeof(copy)); //Непосредствено запись
   ...
   char ssidAp[1000];
   spi_flash_read(0x7c000, (uint32 *)&ssidAp, sizeof(ssidAp)); //Чтение
```

Все работает  но если указываю в очистке адрес не 0x7c а 0x7c000 Как и в других местах не работает запись. Цифра вроде одинакова должна быть. В чем проблема и как исправить может кто то знает. (Хочу перевести адреса в десятичною систему, но пока не решу данный вопрос ето не возможно)

**===Структурирую Ответ===**

Спасибо ответу разобраться Все заработало как нужно.

7C000 = 507904 (Байта)

7C = 124 (Просто Номер)

Размер сектора в байтах = 4096

Байт с которого начинается запись  = 507904
Номер сектора который будит стерт = 124

Получилось начальный сектор с которого начинаться стирание = Номер * Размер = 124 * 4096;

**В таком случаи с в десятичной системе это будит так**

```
spi_flash_erase_sector(124);
spi_flash_write(507904, (uint32 *)&copy, sizeof(copy));
```

или

```
int Num = 124;
spi_flash_erase_sector(Num);
spi_flash_write(Num * 4096, (uint32 *)&copy, sizeof(copy));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spi_flash_erase_sector - просит номер сектора, а не байта.

Размер сектора 4096 == 0x1000

Сектор с адресом 0x7c000 соответсвенно имеет адрес `0x7c000 // 0x1000`
Стирается до `0x7cfff` - учитывай это, если хранишь какие-то данные ещё в этом секторе. Стирание требуется потому что так организованна SPI флешка. Если нужно хранить какие-то данные - лучше подпаять нанд. SPI не предназназначенна для постоянных перезаписей.

Comment: Не совсем понял. тоесть сектор имеет 4096 байт? И мне для стирания нужно указать не номер байта а номер полного сектора?

Comment: 4096 это Биты или Байты?. Так почему spi_flash_erase_sector(0x7c);  spi_flash_write(0x7c000, (uint32 *)&copy, sizeof(copy));  Работает а spi_flash_erase_sector(0x7c000); 
   spi_flash_write(0x7c000, (uint32 *)&copy, sizeof(copy));  Не работает.

Comment: Потому что erase sector стирает 4096 байт, целый сектор.

Comment: 7C000 = 507904
7C = 124
Размер сектора в байтах = 4096
Байт с которого начинается запись  = 507904
Номер сектора который будит стерт = 124
Получилось начальный сектор с которого начинаться стирание = Номер * Размер = 124 * 4096; 
Спасибо разобраться.

В таком случаи с в десятичной системе ето будит так
spi_flash_erase_sector(124);
spi_flash_write(507904, (uint32 *)&copy, sizeof(copy));
или
int Num = 124;
spi_flash_erase_sector(Num);
spi_flash_write(Num * 4096, (uint32 *)&copy, sizeof(copy));